# All Wordpress files are hacked. How to remove the encoded injection?

Tags: php, wordpress, zend-framework, base64

A friend asked me to look up why his WordPress site is not working at all. It turned out it's hacked.

At the beginning of all PHP files an encoded string is injected, something like this:

```
$zend_framework=" .... "; @error_reporting(0); $zend_framework("", "...
```

I have checked the version of WordPress at /wp-includes/version.php and it's  3.5.1.

Have you ever experienced something like this? Do you know a solution of how can I fix these files?

Comment: Gawd, must be an epidemic today! Seems like you're not the first.

Comment: @Fred Perhaps *WordPress sucks*

Comment: @Madbreaks a very big `perhaps` ;-)

Comment: Restore from the last known good backup. It's the only way to be sure. Are all your plugins also up to date?

Comment: my wp blog was also hacked. I uploaded fresh wordpress and exported (backup) all data. and then remove hacked part and uploaded data again with newer version and placed image capache in comments and also disabled xml rpc.

Comment: how did you end up solving this?

Comment: Unfortunately no solution so far, I don't even have an idea how it was hacked. WP 3.5.1 is the newest version so far. I'm not even sure it's WP's fault...